# mysql query not returning specific rows with max(id) data

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using a subquery to get the maximum id from a group.

The query is returning the correct `max(id)` from a group. But what I want as a result out of this table:

```
id--------Name--------GROUP------------Result

1---------ABC----------A----------------Pass

2---------DEF----------B----------------FAIL

3---------GEH----------A----------------Pass

4---------ABC----------B----------------FAIL

5---------DEF----------A----------------FAIL

6---------GEH----------B----------------PASS
```

Is max id's of each group with a result of pass students only?

sorry for the kind of English used to describe my problem.

Comment: Perhaps this has been answered already but otherwise, and for clarity, consider providing the expected result. And yes, for next time 'the kind of English' we prefer is heroic rhyming couplets ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry u r damn funny...thanks i will take care of the points u mentioned in the first line....
But still the problem what i really wanna ask is still not solved.
provably i putted my question in a wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Narayan-this will give the max(id) for each group for students with Result as Pass

```
SELECT MAX(ID)
FROM YourTable
WHERE Result = 'PASS'
GROUP BY `GROUP`;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want groups where **all** students passed use

```
select max(id) as max_id, `group`
from your_table
group by `group`
having sum(result <> 'Pass') = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(ID), GROUP
FROM yourTable
WHERE Result = 'Pass'
GROUP BY GROUP
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select max(id) from tablename where result = 'pass' group by Group;
```

Try this query , hope this helps

note :  change the tablename with required table name.